# initAuth butt where can i get SRPA

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, amazon-cognito

Hi I'm running aws cli

Here is my code

```
aws --region ap-southeast-2 cognito-idp initiate-auth --cli-input-json file://initiate-auth.json
```

and json file

> ```
> {    "AuthFlow": "USER_SRP_AUTH",    "AuthParameters": { 
>   "USERNAME" : "gabrielwu",
>   "SRPA": "?????",
>   "SECRET_HASH":"yyVMuFNZEehJ6Io9WZWUsngJFBVdsjqwX1zMyRhe+Bg="    },    "ClientId": "31vegbhbi2hesihbc0m4h5r8p1" }
> ```

well i don't know how i can generate SRPA. I know how to use Python. Is there any Python library can help this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be quite late but refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526205/implementing-user-srp-auth-with-python-boto3-for-aws-cognito) stackoverflow post. It contains the link to such a library and some very good pointers about how the SRP and ChallengeResponse works.