# AWS Cognito Authentication USER_PASSWORD_AUTH flow not enabled for this client

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito

I have an mobile app with user pool (username & password). The app works fine with aws-amplify sdk. But, wanted to move the code out to Lambdas. So, I have written the following Lambda using Boto3.

Here is Lambda:

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
    response = client.initiate_auth(
        ClientId='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
        AuthParameters={
            'USERNAME': 'xxxxxx',
            'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxx'
        }
    )
    return response
```

Tried admin_initiate_auth too.

```
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
    response = client.initiate_auth(
        UserPoolId='xxxxxxxxx',
        ClientId='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
        AuthParameters={
            'USERNAME': 'xxxxxx',
            'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxx'
        }
    )
    return response
```

Here is the error the I get.

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the
>   InitiateAuth operation: USER_PASSWORD_AUTH flow not enabled for this
>   client: InvalidParameterException Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 12, in lambda_handler
>       'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx'   File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 317, in _api_call
>       return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)   File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 615, in _make_api_call
>       raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name) InvalidParameterException: An error occurred
>   (InvalidParameterException) when calling the InitiateAuth operation:
>   USER_PASSWORD_AUTH flow not enabled for this client

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 114):

Figured it. I have goto user pool - > app clients - >show details -> Enable username-password (non-SRP) flow for app-based authentication (USER_PASSWORD_AUTH).

That fixed it.

Comment: I was having the same issue and your question appeared on the first page of search. It resolves my prob. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting "Initiate Auth method not supported.", tried with boto3==1.7.30 and awscli==1.16.3, which versions worked for you?

Comment: for AWS CDK you need to provide `enabledAuthFlows: [AuthFlow.USER_PASSWORD]` in appClient Construct.

Comment: Perhaps this has moved.  It is now under Your User Pools -> (the user pool) -> General Settings -> App Clients -> Show Details -> Enable username password based authentication (ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH)     It is NOT under App Integration -> App Client Settings

Comment: if someone is interested in more secure way, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43046495/9163608

Comment: In the continual searching for the correct setting in the dashboard, it now appears to be Your User Pools -> (the user pool) -> App Integration -> App Client List -> (the app client name) -> App Client Information -> Edit -> Authentication flows -> Select authentication flows -> ALLOW_ USER_PASSWORD_AUTH

Comment: Thaks for providing the answer! :-)

Answer (score 18):

Figured it. I have goto user pool - > app clients - >show details -> Enable username password auth for admin APIs for authentication (ALLOW_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH).

Comment: First choice in the "Auth Flows Configuration" section: https://imgur.com/a/9G4WkN1

Comment: Any idea how to set this flag programatically in Amplify?

Comment: Not, have you checked the Amplify Documentation?

Answer (score 5):

**A picture is worth a thousand words**

- Go to the Cognito Service

[image]

- Then, select the app client

[image]

- Finally, edit the authentication workflows

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For me I found that my credentials needed a hmac here is the class in case it is useful to someone.

```
import boto3
import boto3.session
import hmac, base64, hashlib
from botocore.client import ClientMeta

class AwsAuth(object):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''

    def gettoken(self):
        if self.token:
            return self.token
        else:
            return False

    def connect(self):

        if not self.username:
            self.username = raw_input("Username: ")

        if not self.password:
            self.password = raw_input("Password: ")

        digest = self.gethmacdigest(self.username)

        response = self.client.initiate_auth(
            ClientId=self.clientid,
            AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
            AuthParameters={
                'USERNAME': self.username,
                'PASSWORD': self.password,
                'SECRET_HASH': digest
            },
            ClientMetadata={
                'UserPoolId': self.userpoolid
            }
        )
        self.token = response
        return response

    def gethmacdigest(self, username):

        message = username + self.clientid
        dig = hmac.new(self.clientsecret, msg=message.encode('UTF-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()    
        return base64.b64encode(dig).decode()


    def __init__(self, path, url, fileout, filein, userpoolid, clientid, clientsecret, region, username = None, password = None):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''

        #boto3.set_stream_logger('botocore', level="DEBUG")

        self.path = path
        self.url = url
        self.fileout = fileout
        self.filein = filein
        self.userpoolid = userpoolid
        self.clientid = clientid
        self.clientsecret = clientsecret
        self.region = region
        self.token = ""

        boto3.setup_default_session(region_name=region) 

        self.client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
        if username is not None:
            self.username = username
        else:
            self.username = None
        if password is not None:
            self.password = password
        else:
            self.password = None
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Cognito Service
[image]

Then, select the app client

Click Edit , And Select **USER_PASSWORD_AUTH**

[image]

[image]

After That I have tried to login & Got Successful Response :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after many attempts .
Here is my solution

1. Go to Cognito from AWS console
2. Then click on the desired pool for which you are facing the error \
3. Now click on the `App Clients` option on the left panel . It will show you available clients
4. Click on `Show Details` for your desired app client. And then in the `Auth Flows Configuration` section make sure `Enable username password based authentication (ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH)` is checked.

For more details on the API refer to this link [InitiateAuth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html#CognitoUserPools-InitiateAuth-request-AuthParameters)

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.Inspite of AuthFlow pass ExplicitAuthFlows then it should work.
`

```
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
    response = client.initiate_auth(
        UserPoolId='xxxxxxxxx',
        ClientId='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        ExplicitAuthFlows='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
        AuthParameters={
            'USERNAME': 'xxxxxx',
            'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxx'
        }
    )
    return response
```

`

Comment: But `AuthFlow` is a `REQUIRED` parameter.

Comment: Yeah it is a required parameter. ExplicitAuthFlows is actually calling AuthFlow only.